# Python how to get permutations one by one

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm looking for code which gives me permutations of the numbers in the range 0-9.

The permutations should be of length `x` and the numbers can repeat.

I want to get these permutations one by one. When I find the permutations I need, I don't need the remaining ones.

All possibilities I have found so far give me all permutations simultaneously and it takes too much time to generate all of them.

Comment: completely unclear what you're asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.permutations`. It gives permutations one at a time and you can stop whenever you want.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = itertools.permutations(range(3))
>>> next(x)
(0, 1, 2)
>>> next(x)
(0, 2, 1)
>>> next(x)
(1, 0, 2)
```

Comment: I try that but i need to get all of posibilities of combination including repeating numbers example: (1,1,1)

Comment: Perhaps `itertools.product` with the `repeat` keyword set to whatever your `x` is?

Comment: I try that but ittertools.prduct give me all of permutation in one time and I can`t take it one by one.

Comment: @Tomasz no it is a generator that by definition will give them one at a time ... this is exactly the right answer ...